# TextBlock line break from dymamic resources

Tags: wpf, xaml, newline, textblock

There is some markup for resources (&#x0d;&#x0a; is a analog of \r\n)

```
    <Application.Resources>
      <system:String x:Key="key1">Line1&#x0d;&#x0a;Line2</system:String>
    </Application.Resources>
```

and for main window:

```
   <Grid>
      <TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource key1}"/>
   <Grid>
```

But the result is only one line: "Line1  Line2". What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextBlock` ignores whitespace when using its Text property. The only way to add line breaks is to use the Inlines property. While this is a read-only property that cannot be set directly, it is also the content property of the `TextBlock`, and thus can be set like so:

```
<TextBlock>
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="key1" />
</TextBlock>
```

You will not be able to use `DynamicResource` though, since Inlines is not a dependency property.

Also, for whitespace to be preserved in XML, you will need to add `xml:space="preserve"` to your string (`xml` is a predefined namespace, no need to declare it):

```
<system:String xml:space="preserve" x:Key="key1">Line1&#x0d;&#x0a;Line2</system:String>
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply set the `xml:space="preserve"` in your string resource like this and it will work as expected -

```
<system:String xml:space="preserve" x:Key="key1">Line1&#x0d;&#x0a;Line2</system:String>
```